# Map of Wikimedia Commons pictures

Tags: android, images, maps, mediawiki, wikimedia-commons

## Context

While doing tourism, I use the [Wikimedia Commons app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wikimedia.commons) to send pictures of monuments to [Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/) (a repository of free media).

Most minor monuments are not on Commons, but the Eiffel Tower has already 1000s of pictures, and my smartphone's camera is not going to produce a better one.

So, I would like to check what pictures of the area are already on Commons.

FYI: [Example of a picture with geolocation attributes on Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Panorama_Kirchplatz_H%C3%BCffen_2.jpg).

## Question

Is there an app or website that shows Wikimedia Commons pictures on a map?

*I am NOT talking about Wikipedia articles. I am talking about Wikimedia Commons pictures.*

Requirements:

- Show all pictures that have geolocation attributes on Commons.
- Preferably thumbnails on a map, but a list sorted by proximity is OK too.
- Free, ideally Open Source.

Bonus:

- Center to my current position.
- Search a location. For instance searching for "Leesburg" will center the map on Leesburg.
- In addition to pictures that have geolocation attributes, also show pictures that have no such attributes but have a geographical category, for instance pictures in the category [[VillageTownA]] should be shown at the location of VillageTownA if they have no individual geolocation.
- Sensible zoom, depending on the number of nearby pictures. Zoom should not be the same in the middle of the Sahara desert and in Manhattan.
- Click on thumbnail to view picture full-screen.
- Reasonably low bandwidth usage.

An acceptable solution could be to transform the [coordinates of all Commons pictures (SQL file, 200MB)](http://toolserver.org/~dispenser/dumps/coord_commonswiki.sql.gz) to [.osm](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) with each point having an URL to the image.

Comment: I have not tried any of the solutions myself, but you might wish to check my [AR list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=4#group_16) for some examples. I guess [Wikitude](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.wikitude) might be an option (not quite matching your map idea, maybe), or some map overlay apps like [mixare](http://www.appbrain.com/app/org.mixare) / [Layar](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.layar) with the [WikiMedia Layers](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Wiki_Loves_Monuments_2011/Tools). All just pointers, hence no answer, sorry…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WikiShootMe](https://tools.wmflabs.org/wikishootme) is currently the most modern desktop tool for this.

In the upper-right, click the Layers button and deselect all but "Commons images".

[image]

- Show all pictures that have geolocation attributes on Commons: Yes
- Thumbnails on a map: Not thumbnails unfortunately, just points
- Free: Yes
- Open Source: Yes
- Center to my current position: Yes
- Search a location: Yes
- Click on thumbnail to view picture full-screen: Yes
- Reasonably low bandwidth usage: Yes

Answer (score 4):

http://wma.wmflabs.org/ is a map with all Commons pictures.

For zoom levels with too many pictures, only the best pictures are shown.

Free.

**Problem**: Very difficult to find the place you want, because there is no search, [no way to enter a latitude/longitude](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60577/how-to-specify-a-target-at-http-toolserver-org-dschwen-wma), and city names are not displayed.

Comment: I big plus on pointing on the problems as well.

Answer (score 1):

[GeoCommons](https://toolserver.org/~para/GeoCommons/) is a project to show geocoded images from Wikimedia Commons in Google Earth.

You can take the KML file, and use it on Android with a KML-compatible navigation app. Using it in OsmAnd would probably require first transforming to `.osm` then `.obf`.

Free.

Answer (score 1):

In the file description of geocoded images from Wikimedia Commons you can find a link that shows you the images in OSM, Google or Bing maps (mostly the camera position, sometimes only the object location). 
Link example OSM:

https://tools.wmflabs.org/wiwosm/osm-on-ol/commons-on-osm.php?zoom=14&lat=42.874&lon=74.598

I cannot guarantee that it is working all night and day, but at least sometimes.

Comment: I see that toolserver is shutting down in 1 1/2 months. - being migrated to [tool labs](http://tools.wmflabs.org/) though.

Comment: I get "The GeoCommons database is currently unavailable, please try again later" just like when using http://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://toolserver.org/~para/GeoCommons/GeoCommons-simple.kml

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I wanted to place pictures from wikimedia on a map.
I created the map here but it's very basic: https://tbo47.github.io/wikimedia/

I also created a javascript/typescript library to get the pictures in an area. So everyone can create their own map if they know javascript: https://github.com/tbo47/ez-opendata

Answer (score 0):

The [Android Commons app](https://commons-app.github.io/) now has this feature, in `Explore`>`Maps`:

[image]

Free and open source. Centered on user location by default. Map can be navigated, zoomed in/out. Tap a thumbnail then `Details` to see the full image.